# Large-Scale Matrix Routing API Billing Question

Tags: here-api

I just need one point of clarification on your Matrix. Your FAQ says:

> One Transaction is counted for every 20 Elements in a Large-Scale Matrix Routing API Request. The number of Elements equals the number of start points times the number of destination points. Large-Scale Matrix Routing Requests generating less than 100,000 individual elements are always counted as 5,000 Transactions.

So if we had 317 origins and 317 destinations (thereby around 100,000 individual elements), can you confirm that this will be treated as 5,000 'Transactions'?

Comment: Perhaps add a link to the FAQ you are quoting, so we know what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The number of elements in your request given `317` origins and `317` destinations will be `100489` which is more than `100,000` and therefore will **not** be counted as `5,000` transactions. 
The page you quoted states that only elements less than `100,000` will be counted as `5,000` transactions.
https://developer.here.com/faqs#payment-and-subscription

For specific pricing details and plans please contact our Sales:
https://developer.here.com/help#how-can-we-help-you

Comment: Many thanks for coming back to me. I did contact sales and they told me to post my question on stack overflow so here I am! So how would the 100,489 elements be transposed into the number of transactions then? Or is 100,000 the limit per call for this method? Many thanks :)